# Ajax.BeginForm - Hook validation events

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-ajax

What I'm doing is disabling the submit button when it's clicked. The Ajax call is somewhat long-running; it takes a couple of seconds to return. So I'm preventing eager users from multisubmitting. The problem comes when the form fails due to validation errors. Without a way to hook an event then there's no way to tell if the submit button needs renabling.

The ASP.Net MVC Documentation leads me to believe there's no such event to hook. Is there a way to hack this to enable what I need?

Edit: I forgot to mention the form is doing client-side validation. A la

```
<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
```

Edit: neither OnComplete nor OnFailure fires when client-side validation fails. Note that OnFailure only fires when the controller action fails, not when validation fails.

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the button in the [OnBegin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.onbegin.aspx) callback and reenable it in the [OnComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.oncomplete.aspx) callback.

Comment: Hmm, does OnComplete fire after a failed validation? I'll check.

Comment: No, no it doesn't. Note the edit I made to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice that there is also an [OnFailure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.onfailure.aspx) callback? Disable it in the [OnBegin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.onbegin.aspx) and reenable in the [OnFailure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.onfailure.aspx).

Comment: Nope, OnFailure doesn't fire either. See my edits; I posted more info. I have found a work-around and will post when I get a chance.